# How to filter response from array of values?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that gets the IP info of the user to determine what country they are from to show local news. I would like to filter the response through an array of supported country codes and if there is no match, return a default value

Im new to Rxjs so im not sure if there is a way of doing this, I know how to do it with the response in normal JS, looping through and checking the equality but i would prefer it, if it can be done all in one place.

```js
// A list of around 40 country codes
const supportedCountries = ["ae", "ar", "at", "au", "be", "bg" .....] 



return this.http.get(`${this.ipUrl}/${endpoint}?${this.ipKey}`).pipe(
   map(({ country_code }: any) => country_code),
   filter(code => code === supportedCountries)
);
```

I expect the output to return a supported country code in the array, if it is not in the array it would output a default code.

**Edit: Looks like i missunderstood rxjs filter, here is my solution**

```js
return this.http.get(`${this.ipUrl}/${endpoint}?${this.ipKey}`).pipe(
   map(({ country_code }: any) => country_code),
   map(code => {
      let supportedCode: string = 'gb';
      supportedCountries.forEach(country => {
         if (country === code.toLowerCase()) {
            supportedCode = country;
         }
      });
      return supportedCode;
   })
);
```

**Edit: A cleaner solution by PierreDuc**

```js
return this.http.get(`${this.ipUrl}/${endpoint}?${this.ipKey}`).pipe(
   map(({ country_code }: any) => country_code.toLowerCase()),
   map((code) => supportedCountries.includes(code) ? code : 'gb')
);
```

Comment: filter() doesn't allow doing that. filter only allows to... filter events being emitted, i.e. prevent some events from being emitted. What you want is to emit a different event than the original. That's what map() is for.

Comment: Ahh right ok got it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the result from an observable you have to use `map`. You can get what you want by using `includes`. You can also make it one `map` function, but then you have to use the `toLowerCase()` twice. What ever you find more legible. There are plenty of other options you can do as well:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.ipUrl}/${endpoint}?${this.ipKey}`).pipe(
  map(({ country_code }: any) => country_code.toLowerCase())
  map((code) => supportedCountries.includes(code) ? code : 'gb')
);
```

<sub>Also try to avoid using `any` by typing all the objects</sub>

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Are you `subscribing`after you do your `pipe(...).subscribe()` or in the calling method?

Also as [PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc) says, you don't want to use `any` because if it not type safe and makes it difficult on yourself later when you want to refactor. Always use an interface (model) and intellisense be your guide.

Here's an example that works for me:

```
export interface CountryCode {
  country_code: string[]
}

const supportedCode = 'gb'

getCountryCodes(endpoint: string): Observable<CountyCode> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ipUrl}/${endpoint}?${this.ipKey}`).pipe(
       map(country_code => country_code),
       filter(codes => codes === supportedCode)
    );
}
```

However, in all actuality, the backend should bring back all the data you need to use on the frontend, and will prevent you filtering on the frontend. In wish case you wouldn't need the `filter(codes => codes === supportedCode)` you'll simply in your component:

```
this.getCountryCodes(this.endPoint)
.pipe(
tap(codes => this.countryCodes = codes)
).subscribe();
```